# Laravel query builder strange result with join

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a query

```
$orders = DB::table('orders')->where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
```

And this is what I have in view:

```
@foreach ($orders as $order)
   {{ $order->id }}
@endforeach
```

It prints out 1 2 3, because the table has these three IDs.
But if I try to join, I get a rather unpredicted result.

```
$orders = DB::table('orders')->where('user_id', $user->id)->
leftJoin('status', 'orders.status_id', '=', 'status.id')
->get();
```

It gives 2 1 1. Result is the same with rightJoin() and join().

I thought this command would append row from status table to every corresponding row of orders table. Join on orders.status_id = status.id.
Can I get an intended result?

Comment: Ambiguity. `id` exists twice, alias the ID out. Alternatively, define the relationship in the model, you won't have have to do any aliasing then.

Comment: Which id exists twice? I am trying to join on status_id and id.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy refers to the id of the status table. Try adding a ```->select('orders.*')```

Comment: add a select with different aliases so you don't get an ambiguity error like Ohgodwhy said, `->select('orders.id as order_id', 'status.id as status_id', ..., ..., ...)`. Now on the view side, instead of `{{ $order->id }}` it would be `{{ $order->order_id }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried `->select('orders.*')` but it did not change the result.

But still, I needed to alias everything out, as suggested in the comments here. So here is my final query.

```
$orders = User::find($user->id)->orders()->
select('orders.id as order_id', 'status.id as status_id', 
'status.label as label', 'orders.ordered_at as ordered_at')
->leftJoin('status', 'orders.status_id', '=', 'status.id')
->get();
```

Probably this could be done in more pretty way, but this works.
Thank you who commented the post.

UPD: Now, I have fixed relations between my models and I can do this much simpler. As described here [Laravel Many-to-one relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143426/laravel-many-to-one-relationship)

```
$orders = Order::with('status')->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->get();
```