# Laravel Many-to-one relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables:

```
orders
-id
-status_id

status
-id
-label
```

Relations are:

Any Order has one status

```
public function status()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Status');
}
```

Any Status can belong to many orders

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order');
}
```

I suppose it is correct?

Now,if I use:

```
    $o = Status::with('orders')->get();
```

I get all the orders. 
If I use:

```
    $o = Order::with('status')->get();
```

I get an error!
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'status.order_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `status` where `status`.`order_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
But I don't have status.order_id, instead I have order.status_id.

How do I get the label of order's status? Like **order->status->label**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`hasMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) for a one-to-many relation. Your orders function should be like this:

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
}
```

The function for `status` should be [`belongsTo`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse).

```
public function status()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Status');
}
```

[`belongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) is used for many-to-many relation with a pivot table.

Comment: But would it then translate to human language like "Order belongs to status. Status has many orders"? This is kind of counterintuitive, but it works just great!